# Структуры и интерфейсы в go

Tags: golang

Только начал изучать go по лекциям от мэил ру и вот возникло несколько вопросов:

1) Как понять запись`sa := SecretAgent{Person: Person{"James", "12312321321"}, LicenseToKill: true}`, а именно `Person: Person{"James", "12312321321"}` это что за JS такой? Полный код:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
    Name string
    inn  string
}

type SecretAgent struct {
    Person
    LicenseToKill bool
}

func (p Person) GetName() string {
    return p.Name
}

func main() {
    sa := SecretAgent{Person: Person{"James", "12312321321"}, LicenseToKill: true}
    fmt.Println("secret inn", sa.GetName())
}
```

2) Почему, когда реализуешь методы интерфейса, принципиально важно принимать ссылку на родителя именно по значению, а не указателю? Т.e. есть код:

```
package main

type Walk interface {
    Fly()
}

type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func (p Person) Fly() {
    println("gg")
}

func main() {
    p := Person{"gg"}
    zz(p)
}

func zz(f Walk) {
    b := f.(Person)
    println(b.Name)
}
```

И он работает, но стоит поменять `func (p Person)` на `func (p *Person)` и все ломается при передаче стуктуры в функцию принимающую интерфейс. Я так понял, что это сделано потому, что интерфейс ничего не знает о данных и следовательно не может их менять по указателю. Я прав?

Comment: У вас тут 2 несвязанных вопроса, почему бы вам их не разбить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `SecretAgent{Person: Person{"James", "12312321321"}...`

   Person до двоеточия означает название поля в структуре SecretAgent. Несмотря на то что структура Person вложена в SecretAgent - к ней всё равно можно обращаться как к полю. При этом имя поля соответствует названию вкладываемой структуры.

   Person после двоеточия означает имя создаваемой структуры. В фигурных скобках - значения полей создаваемой структуры в порядке их объявления в типе структуры. В таком варианте создания структуры - где значения полей указываются без их имён обязательно должны быть присвоены значения всем полям.
2. Важно не "принимать ссылку на родителя именно по значению", а использовать в качестве интерфейса правильные типы - т.е. если метод реализован у указателя, то и интерфейсу соответствует указатель на структуру, а не сама структура.

   Например:

   ```
   package main

   type Walk interface {
       Fly()
   }

   type Person struct {
       Name string
   }

   func (p *Person) Fly() {
       println("gg")
   }

   func main() {
       p := Person{"gg"}
       zz(&p)
   }

   func zz(f Walk) {
       b := f.(*Person)
       println(b.Name)
   }
   ```